# Acumulados de Venta de Un Periodo Pasado

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente código que empieza así:

```
# Import Libraies
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#Montarte a Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

ruta = '/content/drive/MyDrive/example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(ruta)
df.head(10)
```

El archivo que importo, lo pueden descargar de aqui:
[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHNuHbWUL6FUqaAQGmjXlSITtHKrILgV/view?usp=sharing)

Y se ve la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después lo que hago es agrupar los valores y luego crear una métrica llamada Rolling Year (RY_ACTUAL) y (RY_LAST), estas me sirven para conocer la venta de cada categoría, por ejemplo la categoría Azul, doce meses atrás. Esta métrica funciona bien:

```
# ROLLING YEAR
# I want to make a Roling Year for each category. Thats mean how much sell each category since 12 moths ago TO current month

# RY_ACTUAL One year have 12 months so I pass as parameter in the rolling 12
f = lambda x:x.rolling(12).sum()
df_group["RY_ACTUAL"]  = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f)

# RY_24 I create a rolling with 24 as parameter to compare actual RY vs last RY
f_1 = lambda x:x.rolling(24).sum()
df_group["RY_24"]  = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f_1)

#RY_LAST Substract RY_24 - RY_Actual to get the correct amount. Thats mean amount of RY vs the amount of RY-1
df_group["RY_LAST"]  = df_group["RY_24"] - df_group["RY_ACTUAL"]
```

Mi problema esta en la métrica llamada `Year To Date`, que no es otra cosa que los acumulados de venta de cada categoría desde ENERO hasta el mes donde leas la tabla, por `ejemplo` si me paro en Marzo 2015, saber cuanto vendió cada categoría de `Enero a Marzo`. La columna que cree llamada YTD_ACTUAL me hace justamente eso y la logre de la siguiente forma:

```
# YTD_ACTUAL
df_group['YTD_ACTUAL'] = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY","DATE"]).Sales.cumsum()
```

Sin embargo lo que no he podido realizar es la columna `YTD_LAST`, es decir del periodo pasado, que siguiendo el ejemplo anterior donde estaba parado en Marzo 2015, supongamos en la categoría azul, debería de regresarme cuanto fue el acumulado de ventas para la categoría azul de ENERO a MARZO pero del 2014.

Mi intento >.<

```
#YTD_LAST
df_group['YTD_LAST'] = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY", "DATE"]).Sales.apply(f)
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a realizar correctamente esta columna?

¡¡¡De antemano mil gracias comunidad!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Fue un buen ejercicio resolver tu pregunta

Antes que nada, me parece que tu cálculo de `YTD_ACTUAL` no es del todo correcto, lo hice tal como lo pusiste en la pregunta pero no me funcionó (Calcula el acumulado total por categoría sin importar el año), lo que yo hice para calcular la suma acumulada por categoría por año fue lo siguiente:

```
df_group['YTD_ACTUAL'] = df_group.groupby(['CATEGORY', df_group['DATE'].dt.year]).Sales.cumsum()
```

Es importante agrupar por categoría y por el año de tu fecha (`df_group['DATE'].dt.year`), de lo contrario la suma acumulada no se calcula correctamente

Ahora, para calcular el `YTD_LAST` hay que hacer un `shift()` pero hay que tener cuidado con encontrar la categoría correcta y el mes correcto para que al desplazar los valores se posicionen en la fila correcta

Para eso hay que agrupar por categoría y por mes (`df['DATE'].dt.month`) y luego desplazar los valores con `shift()`

```
df_group['YTD_LAST'] = df_group.groupby(['CATEGORY', df['DATE'].dt.month])['YTD_ACTUAL'].shift()
```

**Edición:**

Después de leer tu comentario comprobé los resultados y funciona de forma correcta,  adjunto imagen. Tal vez hay otras fórmulas en el proceso para obtener tus valores que no están escritas en tu pregunta

[image: Captura de pantalla de los resultados]

Adjunto el código completo que hice para las pruebas

```
# Import Libraies
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') 
df_group = df
# ROLLING YEAR
# I want to make a Roling Year for each category. Thats mean how much sell each category since 12 moths ago TO current month

# RY_ACTUAL One year have 12 months so I pass as parameter in the rolling 12
f = lambda x:x.rolling(12).sum()
df_group["RY_ACTUAL"]  = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f)

# RY_24 I create a rolling with 24 as parameter to compare actual RY vs last RY
f_1 = lambda x:x.rolling(24).sum()
df_group["RY_24"]  = df_group.groupby(["CATEGORY"])['Sales'].apply(f_1)

#RY_LAST Substract RY_24 - RY_Actual to get the correct amount. Thats mean amount of RY vs the amount of RY-1
df_group["RY_LAST"]  = df_group["RY_24"] - df_group["RY_ACTUAL"]
# YTD_ACTUAL
df_group['YTD_ACTUAL'] = df_group.groupby(['CATEGORY', df_group['DATE'].dt.year]).Sales.cumsum()
#YTD_LAST
df_group['YTD_LAST'] = df_group.groupby(['CATEGORY', df['DATE'].dt.month])['YTD_ACTUAL'].shift()
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Primero que nada muchas gracias a la persona que se tomo el tiempo de entender este ejercicio, creo que nadie mas lo hizo, por lo cual aceptare tu respuesta como la correcta.

Sin embargo, publico también mi respuesta, que despues de muchos topes de cabaza puede conseguir pues hay algo que no realiza tu código.

Vamos por partes, es cierto, como hay huecos entre fechas y para que funcione correctamente la función `shift` hice el siguiente df y lo uní con un `merge`:

```
d = pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01",end="2022-01-01", freq='MS')
dates = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":d})
df_merge = pd.merge(dates, df, how='outer', on='DATE')
df_merge.head(5)
```

Después lo que hice para obtener la columna requerida `YTD_LAST` fue un procedimiento mucho mas largo y complejo que la respuesta anterior:

```
# # YEAR TO DATE
df_merge["YEAR"] = pd.to_datetime(df_merge["DATE"], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.year 

df_merge = df_merge.sort_values(by=["DATE","YEAR","MONTH"], ascending = True)

# # YTD_ACTUAL

df_merge['YTD_ACTUAL'] = df_merge.groupby(["YEAR","CATEGORY"]).Sales.cumsum()

#YTD_LAST
allDataframes = []
for cat in df_merge['CATEGORY'].unique():
  print(cat)
  fil_cat = df_merge['CATEGORY'] == cat
  cate = df_merge[fil_cat]
  cate["YTD_LAST"] = cate.YTD_ACTUAL.shift(12)
  df = cate.copy()
  allDataframes.append(df)

allDataframes[0]
for i in range(len(df_merge['CATEGORY'].unique())):
  print(i)
  if i == 0:
    cate_fin = pd.concat([allDataframes[i], allDataframes[i+1]], axis = 0)
  cate_fin = pd.concat([cate_fin,allDataframes[i]], axis = 0)

cate_fin.head(50)
```

Porque para mi problema fue necesario hacer todo este procedimiento y no solo como  la respuesta anterior lo tiene, pues porque lo que necesitaba para la columna `YTD_LAST` era comparar los acumulados de cierto año y mes en especifico, Supongamos `Diciembre 2015` vs los acumulados del año parado para ese mismo periodo, es decir `Diciembre 2014` y eso es justo lo que obtengo con el dataframe final `cate_fin`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De nuevo muchas gracias a @HeytalePazguato por detenerse a leer y atacar el caso, bravo!!! y creo que tu solución en otra problemática similar puede servir, pero lo que hace esta solución es darme la venta acumulada del periodo anterior, es decir, si estoy de nuevo en `Diciembre 2015`, lo que me entrega en la columna `YTD_LAST` es lo que hubo en
`Noviembre 2015` para cada categoria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ah, tal vez me hizo falta un parámetro en el shift, voy a corregirlo en la respuesta para que la solución sea válida

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo @HeytalePazguato, un abrazo!

Comment: Buen día, yo creo que hay más valores que estás calculando en tu código, con la información que pusiste en tu pregunta obtengo valores correctos, adjunté captura de pantalla y el código que hice. Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!!